# POST encripted request with JSON body on R

Tags: json, r, openssl, httr, jsonlite

I am trying to use R to post an encrypted request to an [API](https://bitso.com/api_info#creating-and-signing-requests).

Specifically the **/v3/orders/** request.

It requires the use of an API `key` and `secret`, as well as an increasing `nonce`.

Using `openssl`, `jsonlite` and `httr` libraries:

The body has to be JSON encoded:

```
book<-"btc_eth"
side<-"sell"
major<-"0.1"
price<-"100"
type<-"limit"

Payload<-toJSON(data.frame(book=book,side=side,major=major,price=price,type=type))
```

It also requires an authorization header constructed with an **sha256** encrypted `signature`.

```
N<-NONCE() # "1503033312"

method<-"POST"

Path<-"/v3/orders/"

Signature<-sha256(paste0(N,method,Path,Payload),secret)

header<-paste0("Bitso ",key,":",N,":",Signature)
```

Finally the request should look like this:

```
url<-"https://api.bitso.com/v3/orders/"

r<-POST(url, body = Payload, add_headers(Authorization=header))
```

I have been able to post requests with an empty payload to this API before, but this call sends unsupported media type error, something about the way I'm JSON encoding the paylod is causing this.

There's Ruby and PHP examples on how to place this request [here](https://bitso.com/api_info#creating-and-signing-requests).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally was able to send the request.

I have to thank Colin Fay for his response on how to eliminate the brackets.

The thing was, the header had to be constructed with the unbracketed JSON body, but the body had to be sent as a list with automatic JSON encoding as following:

```
NC<-NONCE()

mthd<-"POST"

Pyld<- toJSON(data.frame(book=book,side=side,major=major,price=price,type=type))

Pyld <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", Pyld)

body<-list(book=book,side=side,major=major,price=price,type=type)

url<-"https://api.bitso.com/v3/orders/"

Pth<-"/v3/orders/"

hdr<-paste0("Bitso ",ky,":",NC,":",sha256(paste0(NC,mthd,Pth,Pyld),scrt))

r<-POST(url, body = body, add_headers(Authorization=hdr),encode="json",verbose())
```

Comment: Where does `NONCE` come from?

Comment: 'NONCE' is a function that returns an increasing unique number, as it is required by the API.

Answer (score 1):

As I haven't got a key to try, this is an answer from a case I was once face to — you might want to change a little bit you JSON call. `toJSON` puts a bracket at each side of you call. So you need to remove them :

```
# Go from
Payload<- jsonlite::toJSON(data.frame(book=book,side=side,major=major,price=price,type=type))
Payload
[{"book":"btc_eth","side":"sell","major":"0.1","price":"100","type":"limit"}] 

# To
Payload <- gsub("\\[|\\]", "", Payload)
Payload
{"book":"btc_eth","side":"sell","major":"0.1","price":"100","type":"limit"}
```

Let me know if it works,

Best,

Colin

Comment: I was able to post my request, removing brackets was crucial.
Thank you for your help.

I have answered my own question.